# How can I connect to the internet in Ubuntu server?

Tags: server

I just installed Ubuntu server, but I can't figure out how to connect to the internet, can any one help me? Doing it through Ethernet or WiFi are both available options and please keep in mind I am new to the terminal. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option1:**

if you are working with dhcp

First of all, make sure that your interface is down

```
sudo ifdown eth0
```

Now edit the interfaces

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

and then add the following lines

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Replace eth0 with the correct number if it's not true.

Now head back , and make interface goes up

```
sudo ifup eth0
```

**Option2:**

For giving static IP.

First of all, make sure that your interface is down

```
sudo ifdown eth0
```

Now edit the interfaces file

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

and then add the following lines

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address <IP Address>
    netmask <Network Mask>
    gateway <Default Gateway>
```

I suppose you know what is Ip,netmask and gateway.

Now for your DNS

```
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

This file should be edited to contain the following lines only

```
nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
```

Replace the values with yours

Now head back , and make interface goes up

```
sudo ifup eth0
```

check this : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConfigurationCommandLine/Automatic

Comment: Do I need to need to input the IP, network mask and gateway values and if so how do I get them? Thanks for your help by the way!

Comment: how are you getting internet? DHCP or you have a static IP ?

Comment: When I run Ubuntu Desktop and I believe I have DHCP.. Under my Network settings, under the Ipv4 tab it says "Automatic (DHCP)", but that's all I know. Would it be easier to plug into an Ethernet cable?

Comment: if you have a dhcp then just plug in your cable anddo option 1 in my answer

Comment: @blenderking you are welcome